# In Spring MVC using jquery ajax with json, getting error : "unsupported media type"

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json, spring-mvc

I am creating Spring MVC application, in JSP I need to send object to controller and then return the object to jsp. But I am getting "Unsupported media type" error. Could someone help me ? below is my code:

** In Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addPerson", method = RequestMethod.POST,
                headers = {"Content-type=application/json" })
@ResponseBody
public Person addPerson(@RequestBody Person person) {
     System.out.println(person.getName());
     return person;
}
```

**In JSP :

```
  $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "addPerson.view",
          data: JSON.stringify({ name: "Adam", age: 30, city: "Paris" }),
          contentType: 'application/json',
          success: function(data) {
            alert(data.name + " has been added");

          },
            error : function(xhr, errorType, exception) {
                var errorMessage = exception || xhr.statusText; 
                alert("error : " + errorMessage);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

@RequestMapping(value = "/addPerson", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes= {"application/json"})

Comment: Why do you think this will change anything?

Comment: That's one of the preferred Spring MVC Configuration. Moreover i remember that header names are case insensitive. Still I would suggest you to try proper case, Content-type instead use Content-Type

Comment: Your suggested annotation is equivalent to OP's current annotation.

Answer (score 0):

For Spring to deserialize JSON from the request body and provide the generated object to a `@RequestBody` annotated parameter, you need to have Jackson (1 or 2) on the classpath. If Spring detects Jackson, it will register a `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` which will do the conversion. This `HttpMessageConverter` can handle `application/json` content. No other default `HttpMessageConverter` can, which is why you get an *Unsupported media type* error.

Comment: I have jackson-core-asl-1.5.3, jackson-mapper-asl-1.5.3 in my classpath.

Comment: @Peter Can you show us (in your question) your classpath, how you set it? Also, consider upgrading.

Comment: @Sotirious : I added in Project properties->Java Build Path-> Libraries. All jars are present there.

Comment: @Peter Please update your question with full logs and stacktrace.

Comment: @Sotirious there is no stacktrace. In ajax call error method I am getting "error : Unsupported media type".

Comment: @peter I meant server logs. Enable them and post them.

Comment: Finally got resolved. Tag <mvc:annotation-driven />  was missing in the  dispather-servlet.xml. Thank you all for your suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8"